# Combine a lot of SQL queries and queryout via bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to combine my more than 60 SQL queries into one query and export the result via BCP to one single `.CSV` file.

I managed to combine them with `UNION ALL` and run 1 BCP command, that worked with 2 queries, but not with > 40 :-)

I get an error:

> Query hints exceed maximum command buffer size of 8191 bytes (24324 bytes input)

The queries are almost identically, only the `Location` at the end is different each time.

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(REPLACE(LEFT(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, LEN(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)])) -18 ),'.', ','),0) Result 
FROM 
    _DBHERE_ 
WHERE 
    ([Item] = 1) 
    AND ([Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
    AND ([Location] = '1')

SELECT 
    ISNULL(REPLACE(LEFT(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, LEN(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)])) -18 ),'.', ','),0) Result 
FROM 
    _DBHERE_ 
WHERE 
    ([Item] = 1) 
    AND ([Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) 
    AND ([Location] = '2')
```

Comment: Can't you do this with one query and a join to a Location *table* ?

Comment: Why do you need to specify each query separately if it is only the location that's changing? Surely you could replace this with one query using an IN statement?

Comment: @Simon Sorry I've never heard of IN, but I just tried it and works, the only problem is it now sums the values in one row instead of creating separate rows. And that's of course because of the "SUM" in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT 
[Location]
, ISNULL(REPLACE(LEFT(SUM([Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, LEN(SUM([Sales 
  Amount (Actual)])) -18 ),'.', ','),0) Result 
 FROM 
    _DBHERE_ 
 WHERE [Item] = 1
 AND [Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
 AND [Location] IN ('1', '2', ......) -- replace ... with comma separated list of required values
 GROUP BY [Location]
 ;
```

You only need "AND [Location] IN" line if you are restricting the [Location] value. If you want all locations this line is not necessary. Or as commented you can join on a location table and use any criteria you have to limit the location

**Updated based on comment from OP**
Assuming you have a [Location] table  you could do:

```
SELECT 
L.[Location]
, ISNULL(REPLACE(LEFT(SUM(S.[Sales Amount (Actual)]) * 1.21, LEN(SUM(S.[Sales 
  Amount (Actual)])) -18 ),'.', ','),0) Result 
 FROM [Location] L
 LEFT OUTER JOIN [SalesData] S
 ON S.[Location] = L.[Location]
 AND S.[Item] = 1
 AND S.[Date] = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
 WHERE L.[Location] IN ('1', '2', ......) -- replace ... with comma separated list of required values
 GROUP BY L.[Location]
 ;
```

Comment: Actually, the results aren't what I was expecting :)
I should receive also '0' if the result is empty for that location, instead it doesn't show anything and skips the row.

Comment: do you have a separate location table?

Comment: Can't find it yet, but I could make one? It doesn't change that often.

Comment: If you don't have a location table how are you ensuring integrity of the location column when sales are added? If there is/was a location table -
I'd expect the sales data table would have foreign key constraint on the location table. If that's the case then you can do a left outer join from location table to sales data table and get the output you expect. There are ways without it but IMHO your db design might be in question. Updating answer on assumption you have a location lable